# Missing data and stratified k-fold cross validation of a gbm in R

Tags: r, missing-data, cross-validation, gbm

I have a relatively large data set on sales of homes in several markets in the U.S. For each market, I want to build a Gradient Boosting regression model to predict the sale price. Most of my independent variables (features) have missing values which should be fine for a `gbm` in R.

The `gbm` algorithm in `caret` requires you to specify values of the hyperparameters (`n.trees`, `shrinkage`, `interaction.depth`, `n.minobsinnode`, etc). I want to do a grid search in conjunction with cross validation to pick the best set of hyperparameters:

```
# -------- A function to drop variables that are more than 80% missing or have no variance
Drop_Useless_Vars <- function(datan) {
  n = nrow(datan)
  p = ncol(datan)
  na = is.na(datan)
  n_na = apply(X = na, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sum)
  n_unique = apply(X = datan, MARGIN = 2, function(x) length(na.omit((unique(x)))))
  return(as.data.frame(datan[, -which(n_na > 0.8*n | n_unique < 2)]))
}

# -------- load libraries
library(gbm)
library(caret)

# -------- prepare training scheme
control = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

# -------- design the parameter tuning grid 
grid = expand.grid(n.trees = 10000, 
                   interaction.depth = seq(2, 10, 1), 
                   n.minobsinnode = c(3, 4, 5), 
                   shrinkage = c(0.1, 0.01, 0.001))

# -------- tune the parameters
tuner = train(log(saleprice) ~ ., data = Drop_Useless_Vars(df), method = "gbm", distribution = "gaussian",
              trControl = control, verbose = FALSE, tuneGrid = grid, metric = "RMSE")

# -------- get the best combo
n_trees = tuner$bestTune$n.trees
interaction_depth = tuner$bestTune$interaction.depth
shrinkage = tuner$bestTune$shrinkage
n_minobsinnode = tuner$bestTune$n.minobsinnode
```

The above code works fine except for some markets where missing values are much more frequent. I'm getting the error shown below:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: variable 26: assessor_full_baths has only missing values.
```

`assessor_full_baths` is one of the features in my model. So what's happening is that when the algorithm is sampling data to do the cross validation, one or more of the folds are having variables that are completely missing.

How can I stratify the sampling scheme used by `caret`? That is, how can I force each fold to have the same distribution with respect to the missing values? Also, do you guys know how to make the `gbm` function ignore variables that are completely missing without us telling it which ones they are?

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why are the hyperparameters "so called"? How could the algorithm exclude a feature with all missing values in only 1 fold of cross-validation?

Comment: One of my old professors used to frequently say "so called" when talking about hyperparameters in a Bayesian setting and I guess it got stuck in my head.  Also, I read a paper where these parameters were referred to as regularization parameters which makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a step back and think about how to properly handle the data and fit the model.

Your final modeling data set shouldn't have any missing values, let alone *so many missing values that features are 100% missing in CV folds* (!).

Instead, do a bit of data cleaning and feature engineering:

- you can add NA as a factor level to factor variables
- you can impute missing values in most other situations
- if a feature has high missingness, then you probably need to exclude it, or
- if it's not missing at random and there many be some information you can learn by the fact that it was missing / present, you might create one or a few indicator variables indicating if original feature was missing and/or if it contained a certain level of interest.

If you don't want to impute the missing data then you should use the other strategies mentioned. The missing node is not the same as encoding an NA level. The missing node just means that the tree will give the same prediction as prior to the split where data was missing (see [R gbm handling of missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718648/r-gbm-handling-of-missing-values)). You should never build a model on a feature with high missingness and it would not be a good practice at all to build a model on data with any missing values. Those should be cleaned when you prepare the data set.

Having said that, you can still impute MNAR data. There are a large number of strategies, going back to Heckman's and Rubin's work in the 70's. A lot of people use `mice()` and the *drawn indicator method*.

This may help: http://stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/docs/mnar.pdf

Comment: I do not want to impute missing values because there is no evidence that the missingness is random. Also, my final objective is to use these models to predict the price on a large data set (over 30GB) and I do not intend on imputing that big of a data set (at least for now). Lastly, it was to my understanding that each split in an individual tree in a gbm object  results in 3 nodes: a left node, a right node, and a missing node. That is, it treats missing values as a separate category. Doesn't this accomplishes what you're proposing (i.e. creating indicator variables for missingness)? Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to impute the missing data then you should use the other strategies mentioned. The missing node is not the same as encoding an NA level. The missing node just means that the tree will give the same prediction as prior to the split where data was missing (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718648/r-gbm-handling-of-missing-values). You should never build a model on a feature with high missingness and it would not be a good practice at all to build a model on data with any missing values. Those should be cleaned when you prepare the data set.

Comment: Having said that, you can still impute MNAR data. There are a large number of strategies, going back to Heckman's and Rubin's work in the 70's. A lot of people use `mice` and the drawn indicator method. This may help: http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/docs/mnar.pdf

Comment: I've used `mice` in the past and might use it again here but my question is not about missing data treatment. The `gbm` function also fails if a particular fold of your CV ends up with a categorical variable with only one category. For example, let Xj be the property type which can take on one of three categories: Single Family, Condo, or Other. If 90% of the data are Single Family, you could very well end with a fold with only that category which also causes an error. What I want to do is to stratify the sampling used by `caret` when doing CV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `caret::createFolds` to create the CV folds yourself. You simply need to supply a different `y` variable than your outcome (ie- `saleprice`). You'll want to define a new variable based on your stratification variables... see `?interaction`. This can then be passed to `caret::trainControl`

For example:

```
library(caret)
y2 <- interaction(df$x1, df$x2)
cv_folds <- createFolds(y2, k= 5)
control = trainControl(index= cv_folds, method= "cv", number= 5)
...
```

Or you can avoid using `caret` and write your own [stratified sampling code](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/resume_ex_code/blob/master/stratified_sampling.R)

That said, I agree with most everything @Hack-R said about the practical use of features with missing values and imputation.